# Mini pine tree lost all its needles, is it dead?

Tags: dryness, pines, dead-branch

I have this dwarf pine tree, say 50cm tall, it looked healthy until I decided to expose it to direct sunlight some two months ago.

For two weeks it felt like it was about to produce new stems, like I could see some new little buds on the tip of some branches. Then, all in a sudden, after couple of weeks, it lost all the needles apart of few of them on the extremity of some branches, that stayed brown.

I may have underwatered it. So, I moved it to a much less sunny area, and started water it using also a fertilizer, and after one month not only nothing grew back, but the needles left in place are still brown and dry. The fall to the ground just touching them.

I am afraid it is dead, but I know that some pine trees lose their needles once per year. What do you think?

Comment: A few questions: What kind of pine is it? If you scratch off a bit of bark on a branch, is the branch dry, brown and brittle, or do you see life? And could we get a photo or two?

Comment: Hello Stephie, it is a sort of small pine tree, maybe called christmas tree? It is literally dwarf. Tomorrow I will add some pictures and scratch a branch and see.

Comment: From the size , I would guess Norfolk Island Pine; so not actually a pine. Often sold in the US during Christmas holidays. Wait to next Christmas a buy a new one.